# How to retrieve just the array values only of a nested field of MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to deep query and retrieve specific fields from MongoDB, but unfortunately couldn't able to figure out the correct solution.

**Document data**:

```
[ {
   "_id": 39127198,
   "name": "Mike",
   "details": {
      "age": 25,
      "vehicles":[
         {"brand":"Chevrolet","model":"Silverado","plate":"AB11"}, 
         {"brand":"Jeep","model":"Cherokee","plate":"CG678"}
      ]
   }
}, {
   "_id": 39127198,
   "name": "Taylor",
   "details": {
      "age": 25,
      "vehicles": [
          {"brand":"GMC","model":"Sierra","plate":"748397"}
      ]
   }
} ]
```

**My requirement**: Return "vehicles" array alone for a specific player. Let's say for user "Mike" in this case.

**Here is what I tried**;

```
collection.find( {"name":"Mike"} )
          .project( {"details.vehicles" : 1, "_id": 0, "name": 0} )
          .toArray(function(err, result) { ... } )

collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "name":"Mike" } },
  { $project: {"details.vehicles" : 1, "_id": 0, "name": 0} }
]).toArray(function(err, result) { ... } )
```

**Here is what I get for the above code**:

```
[
   {
     "details": {
       "vehicles": [
         {"brand":"Chevrolet","model":"Silverado","plate":"AB11"}, 
         {"brand":"Jeep","model":"Cherokee","plate":"CG678"}
       ]
     }
   }
]
```

**Expected**:

```
[
   {"brand":"Chevrolet","model":"Silverado","plate":"AB11"}, 
   {"brand":"Jeep","model":"Cherokee","plate":"CG678"}
]
```

I am using MongoClient. MongoDB shell version v4.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $unwind and $replaceRoot stages to achieve this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "name": "Mike"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$details.vehicles"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$details.vehicles"
    }
  }
])
```

Will output exactly what you need.
Hope it helps

Comment: Maybe add `toArray()` to get the exactly requested output

Comment: Awesome, thank you. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
db.vehi.aggregate( [ 
  { $match: { "name":"Mike" } },
  { $project: { "vehicles": "$details.vehicles", "_id": 0 } }
] ).next().vehicles
```

The *exact* output:

```
[
        {
                "brand" : "Chevrolet",
                "model" : "Silverado",
                "plate" : "AB11"
        },
        {
                "brand" : "Jeep",
                "model" : "Cherokee",
                "plate" : "CG678"
        }
]
```

**- OR -**

This also gets the same result:

```
db.vehi.find( 
  { "name" : "Mike" }, 
  { "details.vehicles" : 1, _id : 0 }
 ).next().details.vehicles
```